# Error with `QObject` subclass and copy constructor: `QObject::QObject(const QObject&) is private`

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

The following compile errors is what I have:

```
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include/qobject.h: In copy constructor Product::Product(const Product&):
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include/qobject.h:211: error: QObject::QObject(const QObject&) is private
Product.h:20: error: within this context
HandleTCPClient.cpp: In member function int Handler::HandleTCPClient(int, std::string, std::string):
HandleTCPClient.cpp:574: note: synthesized method Product::Product(const Product&) first required here 
HandleTCPClient.cpp:574: error:   initializing argument 1 of std::string productDetails(Product)
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include/qobject.h: In member function Product& Product::operator=(const Product&):
Product.h:20:   instantiated from void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Product, _Alloc = std::allocator<Product>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:610:   instantiated from âvoid std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Product, _Alloc = std::allocator<Product>]â
HandleTCPClient.cpp:173:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include/qobject.h:212: error: QObject& QObject::operator=(const QObject&) is private
Product.h:20: error: within this context
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc: In member function void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Product, _Alloc = std::allocator<Product>]:
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:260: note: synthesized method âProduct& Product::operator=(const Product&) first required here 
make: *** [HandleTCPClient.o] Error 1
```

Part of my HandleTCPClient.cpp Line 574:

```
            Product tempProduct;// temporary Product storage variable
            tempProduct.setHandler(this);
...

            else if (output[1] == '5') // description
            {
                output.erase(0,2); // erase the sequence numbers
                tempProduct.description = output;
    LINE 574            output = productDetails(tempProduct); // obtain client given information about selling product
            }
```

Product.h::

```
#include <string>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include "HandleTCPClient.h"
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qgl.h>

class Handler;

//Define ourselves a product class
class Product : public QObject
    {

        Q_OBJECT

        void startTimer();

    public:
        Product();

        string seller, itemName, description, highestBidder;
        double price, min, buyingPrice, currentBid;
        int time;
        bool isSold;
        Handler *handler;

        void setHandler(Handler *h);

    public slots:
        void setProductToSold();

    };

#endif
```

Product.cpp::

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "Product.h"

Product::Product()
{
    seller = "";
    itemName = "";
    price = 0.00;
    min = 0.00;
    buyingPrice = 0.00;
    time = 0;
    description = "";
    highestBidder = "None";
    currentBid = 0.00;
}

void Product::setHandler(Handler *h)
{
    handler = h;
}
```

Thanks for all the help =)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Product` is a subclass of `QObject`, which cannot be copied. Your code is attempting to copy it somewhere (perhaps in `productDetails(tempProduct)`) and this causes the error. Perhaps you could pass it to your function by const reference instead; or perhaps some redesign of your program is needed.

Your compiler is telling you that the copy constructor of `QObject` is private, so it cannot be called by any function that is not a method of the base class. Qt has designed it to work that way.

One reason that Qt disables copying of `QObject`s is that it manages the memory of the children of a `QObject`. When a `QObject` gets deleted, so do all of its children. This would be impractical to do properly if the `QObject` was copyable.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation--this just saved me a lot of time. (I was passing by value, not reference in a slot for those coming to this)

Answer (score 4):

Copying is not allowed for QObject descendants...

See http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2001-02/thread00123-0.html

Your productDetails() function takes its parameter by value, making a copy necessary. Change it to take a const reference instead.

Answer (score 2):

On line 574 you are trying to pass one of these items to the productDetails function. You don't show it, but I imagine that this function either takes a value. So the compiler is trying to create a brand new object to pass it, but that's not permitted by the library, which has intentionally set the copy constructor to be private.

Make a new object explicitly, or fix the called function.